# How to setup the current date but with different year

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm working with an app thau use NSDate, it's an app that will be only available for people who has more tha 13 years, so what I want to do is setup the date from the actual date, I mean today but I want to setup the year to 2004 so when I launch the app should appear the actual date, the actual month but the year should be 2004. Right now if the user select a date under 2004 an alert appears, I want to disable this alert and setup the 2004 as default year and then be able to move to any year that the user wants. I'm working with I let the code to validate the year and the code to set the current date, hope you can help me

```
func validateDate () {

        let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -13, to: Date())

        if selectedDate == nil {
            selectedDate = Date()
        }





func changeDateToString (date:Date) -> String {

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: date)

    let year : Int = comp.year!
    let month : Int = comp.month!
    let day : Int = comp.day!


    var stringDay: String = "\(day)"
    var stringMonth: String = "\(month)"
    let stringYear: String = "\(year)"

    if stringDay.characters.count == 1 {
        stringDay.insert("0", at: stringDay.startIndex)
    }

    if stringMonth.characters.count == 1 {
        stringMonth.insert("0", at: stringMonth.startIndex)
    }



    let finalString = stringYear + stringMonth + stringDay + " "

    print(finalString)

    return finalString
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31418374/2303865

Comment: Ok sí, que estaba haciendo eso, pero yo quiero en la vista del calendario aparece el día actual, el mes en curso y el año 2004 como el año por defecto, pero cuando ejecuto la aplicación nada no aparece el año 2004 como mi año por defecto, aparece la fecha de hoy y el año 2017

Comment: What you mean default year? `let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .day], from: date)` you are not getting the year component

Comment: Yes when I setup the current date obviously appears the actual day, month and year in the picker. So what I want is display the current day, month but the year should be 2004 every time that I launch my app and then I can move in the picker normally to select any year that I want.

Comment: `datePicker.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -16, to: Date())`

Comment: As you can see in my first method called validate date, I'm doing this but nothing is changing in the picker still appearing 2017 as the year when should be 2004

Comment: I can't see you setting the datePicker's date property anywhere in your code

Comment: Yes, I wasn't setting up at that point I've already did it, and now it's working properly. Thanks for your help