# How to get only a integer value from UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

What code would I use to have the user type in a number between 18 and 120 for their age?

Something like:

agetextfield  must be = to a number between 18-120

If they type in a string that is not a number, alert the user "Please enter Age as a numerical value e.g 19".

If they type in a number less than 18, alert the user " User must be over the age of 18"

If they type in a number greater than 120, alert the user " User Must be between the ages of 18 and 120.

Comment: Why don't you use a date picker and set a maximum date? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31418374/2303865

Answer (score -1):

You can use this for entry type, it will show a numeric keyboard only.

```
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

And then set the delegate
    textField.delegate = self

so you can use this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if Int(textField.text!)! < 18 || Int(textField.text!)! > 120 {
        // Alert
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many issues with this answer. A user can paste in text. Your use of force-unwrapping will cause lots of crashes.

Comment: @rmaddy where is the duplicate question?

Comment: @benpalmer661 Look at the top of your question.