# Swift get date five years prior to today

Tags: swift

I have this validation code, I want to add another part to it where it checks to make sure that the date selected in not more than fives years in the past from today. Thoughts!

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
    let date1 = dateFormatter.date (from: termStartDate.text!)

    guard let startDate = date1 , startDate < Date() else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Input Error", message: "Select Date less than today", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
```

Comment: You should use UIDatePicker minimum and maximum date. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31418374/2303865

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the date five years back from now with this one-liner:

```
let fiveYearsAgoDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -5, to: Date())
```

Since you may not be using a `UIDatePicker` (many apps use a numeric key pad that inserts separators, such as `/`, between days, months, and years), this is a viable option to validate user input. Otherwise, if using a `UIDatePicker`, setting the maximum and minimum dates is the way to go.